# Why can't VB Parallel.ForEach not infer my loop item type?

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, task-parallel-library, type-inference

I have a class `Parent` which has as property `Items` that is a `List(of Child)`

If I use this code

```
Parallel.ForEach()(parent.Items,
            Sub(item)
                item.DoSomething()
            End Sub)
```

I get a compiler warning `No overload for method ForEach() accepts this count of arguments`

If I change the code to

```
Parallel.ForEach(of Child)(parent.Items,
            Sub(item)
                item.DoSomething()
            End Sub)
```

it works.

However, in c# I can just write

```
Parellel.ForEach(parent.Items, item =>
    {
        item.DoSomething();
    });
```

Why does VB not infer in this case?

Comment: Can you be more specific with the parameter type, using `Sub(item As Child)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first VB example you have an extra set of parentheses so you are calling .ForEach wih no parameters.  Remove them and it will work:

```
Parallel.ForEach(parent.Items,
         Sub(item)
            item.DoSomething()
         End Sub)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the VB compiler to infer the type arguments, you don't provide the type argument `(Of )` brackets:

```
Parallel.ForEach(parent.Items,
        Sub(item)
            item.DoSomething()
        End Sub)
```

In much the same way, as if you want the C# compiler to infer types, you don't provide the type argument `<>` angle brackets.

The error was trying to tell you that what the VB compiler is seeing in your first example is a call to `ForEach` with *no* arguments `()` *followed* by a call on whatever the return value from that first call is.

Comment: shf301 was first, but +1 anyway